# Pop a number on a random position in a two dimension array

Tags: c, game-engine

I am currently working on a project to write a C program to clone the popular iphone game "2048". If you are not familiar with this game, you can visit [here](http://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/) to check it out.

I will just briefly talk about how I am approaching this problem:

1. Generate a table with just two '2's.
2. The user starts to play.
3. The program will pop a '2' on a random position in the 2-dimension array where it is '0'.
4. Check if there is any more moves. If not, game over.

The program structure I wrote currently is:

1. Generate a 2-dimension array.
2. Wrote 4 functions to move the numbers in the array. (MoveUP, MoveDown, MoveLeft, Move Right).
3. Wrote 4 functions to add up the numbers after movement. (AddUp, AddDown, AddLeft, AddRight).
4. Call the move functions again the rearrange the table after adding.
5. Print the matrix and wait for the user for next movement.

And this is part of the code I have for now:

The code is a little bit long.

Right now I couldn't figure out a way to pop a '2' on a random zero tile after each movement. Any help is appreciated.

I am open to suggestions to my existing code too. If you need the entire code, I can give that to you too.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/* The main matrix */
int a[4][4];

/* <- Function declarations begin -> */
void InitMat(int a[4][4]);
void PrintMat(int a[4][4]);
void MoveUp(int a[4][4]);
void MoveLeft(int a[4][4]);
void MoveRight(int a[4][4]);
void MoveDown(int a[4][4]);
void AddUp(int a[4][4]);
void AddDown(int a[4][4]);
void AddLeft(int a[4][4]);
void AddRight(int a[4][4]);

/* -> Function declarations end <- */


/* <- Main function begin -> */
int main(void)
{
    int input;
    /* Initialize the starting matrix */
    InitMat(a);
    /* Display the main matrix */
    PrintMat(a);

    while ((input = getchar()) != 'q')
    {
        switch (input)
        {
        case 'w':
            MoveUp(a);
            AddUp(a);
            MoveUp(a);
            PrintMat(a);
            break;
        case 'a':
            MoveLeft(a);
            AddLeft(a);
            MoveLeft(a);
            PrintMat(a);
            break;
        case 'd':
            MoveRight(a);
            AddRight(a);
            MoveRight(a);
            PrintMat(a);
            break;
        case 's':
            MoveDown(a);
            AddDown(a);
            MoveDown(a);
            PrintMat(a);
            break;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
/* -> Main function end <- */

/* <- Function definitions begin -> */

/* Function1: initializing the main matrix */
void InitMat(int a[4][4])
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    a[1][2] = a[2][2] = 2;
    a[0][0] = 2;
    a[3][0] = 2;
    a[3][3] = 2;
}

/* Function2: Print the main matrix */
void PrintMat(int a[4][4])
{
    printf("+-------+-------+-------+-------+\n");
    printf("|   %d   |   %d   |   %d   |   %d   |\n", a[0][0], a[0][1], a[0][2], a[0][3]);
    printf("+-------+-------+-------+-------+\n");
    printf("|   %d   |   %d   |   %d   |   %d   |\n", a[1][0], a[1][1], a[1][2], a[1][3]);
    printf("+-------+-------+-------+-------+\n");
    printf("|   %d   |   %d   |   %d   |   %d   |\n", a[2][0], a[2][1], a[2][2], a[2][3]);
    printf("+-------+-------+-------+-------+\n");
    printf("|   %d   |   %d   |   %d   |   %d   |\n", a[3][0], a[3][1], a[3][2], a[3][3]);
    printf("+-------+-------+-------+-------+\n");
}

/* Function3: Move upwards */
void MoveUp(int a[4][4])
{
    int j;
    /* i: rows; j: columns */
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        if (a[0][j] == 0)
        {
            if (a[1][j] == 0)
            {
                if (a[2][j] == 0)
                {
                    if (a[3][j] == 0)
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        a[0][j] = a[3][j];
                        a[3][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    a[0][j] = a[2][j];
                    a[2][j] = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                a[0][j] = a[1][j];
                a[1][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            a[0][j] = a[0][j];
        }

        if (a[1][j] == 0)
        {
            if (a[2][j] == 0)
            {
                if (a[3][j] == 0)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    a[1][j] = a[3][j];
                    a[3][j] = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                a[1][j] = a[2][j];
                a[2][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            a[1][j] = a[1][j];
        }

        if (a[2][j] == 0)
        {
            if (a[3][j] == 0)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                a[2][j] = a[3][j];
                a[3][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            a[2][j] = a[2][j];
        }
    }
}

/* Function7: addition after moving up */
void AddUp(int a[4][4])
{
    int i, j;
    /* i: rows; j: columns */
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (a[i][j] == a[i + 1][j])
            {
                a[i][j] += a[i + 1][j];
                a[i + 1][j] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check the code for the original game (js/html5) . IIRC it just enumerates all empty cells and picks one randomly to put the new '2'.

Comment: @Michelle, yes you are right. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the function `rand()` that generates a random value beetween 0 and the maxint value.

You got to do something like this:

```
#define MAXRANDOMVALUE 3

/.../  //functions and everything

void poprandomtwo() {

int i,j; //your indexs
i=(rand ())%(MAXRANDOMVALUE+1));
j=(rand ())%(MAXRANDOMVALUE+1));
/../ //here comes your job ;)
} 

int main {

    srand(time(NULL)); //do this one time at the beginning of your code to set the seed     
    /.../
    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps